# Why is the toolbar not grayed out by the modal message?

Tags: sencha-touch

Let's say I have this code inside the launch function of a Sencha Touch 2 application.

```
var toolbar = {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Show message',
            listeners: {
                tap: function() {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Some message');
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    docked: 'top'
};

var main = {
    xtype: 'component'
};

Ext.Viewport.add([toolbar, main]);
```

Why the message shown when "Show message" is clicked doesn't gray out the docked toolbar as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toolbar should be a child of `main`, not of the viewport, to be included behind the modal dialog mask. `main` should also be an instance of a `panel`. For example:

```
    ...
    var main = {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [toolbar]
    };

    Ext.Viewport.add(main);
```

Here's a Sencha Fiddle that demonstrates the correct behavior: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8gp

Comment: Thanks for answering. This works perfectly. Could you please tell me why we need to use a panel? I tried with container and seems to work fine as well. I thought panels should be used when we need to show a popup.

Comment: @emanuele Yes a container will work just fine. Use whatever is appropriate for your application.